# Permission error running "Application.CreateItemFromTemplate" method on an EML file

Tags: vba, outlook, permissions

I'm trying to run a macro that copies EML files into my inbox.

When I get to the `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate` line to apply it to an EML file I get a runtime error:

> We can't open [filename.path]. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.

I tried running Outlook as ADMIN. Also tried the `Session.OpenSharedItem` method. I'm using Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO.

Full code:

```vb
Sub ImportMessagesToOutlookFolder()
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim SourceFolderName As String
    Dim FileItem As Scripting.File
    Dim strFile, strFileType As String
    Dim oMsg As Object
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Dim copiedMsg As MailItem
    Dim Savefolder As Outlook.Folder
    
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject 'Source folder

    'Ask for folder with items to import
     SourceFolderName = BrowseForFolder("My Computer")
     Set SourceFolder = fso.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)
    
   'Set the Outlook folder name
     Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set Savefolder = objNS.PickFolder

    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
     
        'Set oMsg = FileItem
        Set oMsg = Outlook.Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(FileItem.Path)
        
        'On Error Resume Next
    
        Set copiedMsg = oMsg.Copy
            
            copiedMsg.Move Savefolder
    
        Set copiedMsg = Nothing
        Debug.Print FileItem.Name & " " & FileItem.DateCreated
        
        oMsg.Delete
        Set oMsg = Nothing
        'FileItem.Delete
    
    Next FileItem

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
      
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the actual file path used for calling the `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate` method?

Comment: Are you sure you are actually opening an OFT or an MSG file?

Comment: Eugene: it's a folder in the documents folder - i've have all permissions and changed attributes, it only has A now, so it should be working fine, but doesnt....

Comment: Dmitry: i'm opening an EML file, not OFT nor MSG

Answer (score 0):

The [Application.CreateItemFromTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitemfromtemplate) method creates a new Microsoft Outlook item from an Outlook template (.oft) and returns the new item. It is not designed for EML files by default. You may try to use the `ShellExecute` method for opening EML in the default application (you can set Outlook, see [Open .eml Files in Outlook](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/open-eml-files-in-outlook/) for more information):

```
Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim objFolder : Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select the folder containing eml-files", 0)

Dim Item
If (NOT objFolder is Nothing) Then
  Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set Folder = objOutlook.Session.PickFolder
  If NOT Folder Is Nothing Then
    For Each Item in objFolder.Items
      If Right(Item.Name, 4) = ".eml" AND Item.IsFolder = False Then
    objShell.ShellExecute Item.Path, "", "", "open", 1
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    Set MyInspector = objOutlook.ActiveInspector
    Set MyItem = objOutlook.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    MyItem.Move Folder
      End If
    Next
  End If
End If

MsgBox "Import completed.", 64, "Import EML"

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
```